# dyld: Library not loaded when installing php 7.4 with brew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, macos-catalina, dyld

I'm trying to install PHP 7.4 with Homebrew on MacOS Catalina. I used the following command:

`brew install php@7.4`

This failed during the post install step with an error about a dyld library:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.4/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
```

I get the same error if I try to run `php` from the command line afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I ran `brew doctor`, which advised me that the `gmp` keg was installed but unlinked (there were actually several versions of gmp installed). I ran:

`brew link gmp`

which added the missing links.

I then ran:

`brew reinstall php --build-from-source`

which was now able to find the gmp library.

Comment: Your tip was good! Works like a charm on macOS Monterey. Thanks.